# Assigning `ConverterParameter` to current window in XAML only?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm struggling to get a basic binding working without resorting to code behind.

I currently have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Goodbye, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource SomeObject}}"></TextBlock>
```

Where I'm having to delve into codebehind to set the resource `SomeObject`:

```
this.Resources["SomeObject"] = this;
```

Is it possible to achieve the same effect in XAML-only?

I've tried using `...ConverterParameter={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}...` which unfortunately passes in the expression rather than evaluating it which I guess makes sense.

Failing that, I think I'm going to scrap `ConverterParameter` and just use a `MultiBinding`, which feels like a bit of a hack.

Comment: The problem you're facing is the exact reason I started using the MVVM pattern. Here's a related question I asked years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116329/how-do-you-pass-data-into-an-ivalueconverter-in-xaml

Comment: Agreed. Generally speaking a multi-converter isn't a "hack", it's how you go about solving this. That said it's worth keeping in mind that converters effectively reside in the view layer and are only marginally better than code-behind. It's the job of the classes you are binding to (i.e. the view model in the case of MVVM) to prepare data in a form that's readily consumed by the front end. If you find yourself having to rely on converters for complex or application-specific tasks then it's often a good indication that the view model isn't doing its job properly.